# Replacing the first n elements of the data frame with a different value, while leaving the rest intact

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I am stuck in something which I have no idea how to get out of it.

The main task I need to accomplish is to randomly increase the n% of my data (here 10% of the total data) entries by a value of 20%. And find the increased value in a separate column while all other non-increased values would be 0. I could not figure out a way to just capture the increased value according to the index. All the data are in a data frame initially. Below is the example of the data I want.

[image]

Help with Replacing the first n elements of the data frame with a different value, while leaving the rest intact.

So, to do this I thought of shuffling the data and increasing the top n% of the data. While I was able to increase the data, I had trouble putting it back into the data frame. After doing the calculations, the value is returned as a list, and when I try putting it back, I get the following error.

```
"Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "household_11", value = list(household_11 = c(360.481, :

replacement element 1 has 14 rows, need 144"



values <- read.csv("C:\\hh_11.csv", header=TRUE)

oneday<- values[1441:1584,] #extracting data for Jan 11

set.seed(42)

shuffled= oneday[sample(1:nrow(oneday)), ]

n = as.integer((10/100)*nrow(oneday)) #select percentage of data to be changed, by 10%

multi <- function(a){

a*1.2 #select the percentage value to be increased, by 20%

}

top <- shuffled %<>% slice(1:10) %>% select("household_11") %>% lapply(FUN = multi)

oneday["household_11"]=top["household_11"]
```

Any help would be extremely helpful. I am completely stuck.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
df <- data.frame(household = round(runif(2000, 100, 2000), 2))
df$household_inc <- df$household
idx <- sample(nrow(df), 0.3*nrow(df))
df$household_inc[idx] <- df$household_inc[idx]*1.2
df$increased_value <- df$household_inc - df$household
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it didn't really address my issue. I have around 2000 rows of data, and I wanted to see the increased value on n% of 2000 data. But this program will not show the 2000 rows, only the selected 10 rows. 

I really appreciate your time.

Comment: My answer will show all the rows in the data. The first line is just creating some dummy data since you didn't provide any other than the screenshot. I updated the dummy data to have 2000 rows. All 2000 remain in the final dataframe.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get that before. too stupid lol.....thank you ...its works right now...really appreciate your effort.